# How to push array inside array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an array. "branches": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], I need to push this array into an array of objects. Here multipleBranch is the array of objects. How to achieve this in javascript?

```
multipleBranch: [
    {
      branches: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    },
]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? what exactly is the challenge here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution as per your description

```
const branches = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

const multipleBranch = [{ branches }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple branches then check the code below

```js
 const multiBranch = [
    {
    "branches": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    }
    ]
    
 const addBranch = (arr) => {
    multiBranch.push({branches:arr});
 }
 
 addBranch([1,2,3]);
 console.log(multiBranch);
```